# how to share public S3 bucket with external user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I work in a company and a client will drop files into one of our s3 buckets. How do we tell them which one?

I keep looking at AWS documentation that describes how to make a bucket public and IAM policies. I already did that.

Now, how to share that? When I go to the bucket properties, there's a "Copy Bucket ARN" button. That just gives me:

```
arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>
```

The real task is to share only with the client. Right now I'm just trying to do this simple test.

I'm not sure if they will drop the file manually or programmatically.

Comment: What's wrong with the ARN? That should be enough, if the bucket is public, or if they have the appropriate IAM permissions, etc.

Comment: They just need the ARN then? When I login as myself (not company user), I go to s3 and search "Public", but I don't see anything, including when I search for that public bucket.

Comment: I believe S3 buckets all share a global namespace (hence bucket names must be globally unique). That's why the ARN looks so simple -- but since every bucket name is unique, that should be enough to identify. As for actually pushing to it, it depends on what program they're using...

Comment: Are you willing to provide the client a set of IAM User credentials? If not, how do you wish to identify the client so that they can be permitted to upload files but nobody else can upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's manually, you could always make them an account to your bucket with the proper permissions, if it's through a website for example, you can create an upload feature that is configured to point and upload to your bucket as long as your policies and permissions are set up correctly.